# How to hack MySQL GROUP_CONCAT to fetch a limited number of rows?

Tags: mysql, limit, group-concat

I somehow need this feature,but MySQL doesn't support it at this moment.

I'm using `GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(...))` to generate a xml-like stuff.

But when the size exceeds the limit,the xml is just broken!

So I have to somehow make it only retrieve 5 rows !

Comment: increase group_concat_max_len value in my.cnf

Comment: may be you can get your answer here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378324/limit-ignored-in-query-with-group-concat

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608464/group-concat-with-limit

Answer (score 22):

I've worked around this using `SUBSTRING_INDEX`.

For example:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Field1 SEPARATOR ','), ',', [# of elements to return])
FROM Table1;
```

Answer (score 5):

An example for Charles answer:

basic:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( field ) FROM ( SELECT field FROM table LIMIT 200 )
```

extended:

CAST can be useful if result are truncated by buffer:

```
SELECT CAST( GROUP_CONCAT( field ) AS CHAR(2048) ) FROM ( SELECT field FROM table LIMIT 200 )
```

Comment: Yes, it will work. But it will need a more complex constuction for a query with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I got an error for "Every derived table must have its own alias" when using the first query.

To fix that, I changed it to " SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( field ) FROM ( SELECT field FROM table LIMIT 200 ) AS alias "

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Not really an answer to your question but a ref for other people who also would want to use a LIMIT clause in GROUP_CONCAT():

A [feature-request](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=30098) was filed long ago to MySql developers. Not yet implemented :-(

Answer (score 2):

Use a temporary table / subquery to limit results?  Without seeing your query, it'll be hard to give solid advice for that route.

However, you may find the `group_concat_max_len` setting to be more useful.  It controls the maximum length of a `GROUP_CONCAT` operation, in string length.  Raise it to prevent broken `GROUP_CONCAT`s, when you can't afford to limit results.

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate the partitioned row_number using user variables and then limit rows and apply group_concat:

Consider the following table:

```
create table your_table (
    id int primary key autoincrement,
    category int,
    value int
);
```

and data:

```
insert into your_table (category, value) 
values
(1,  1), (1,  2), (1,  3), (1,  4), (1,  5),
(2,  6), (2,  7), (2,  8), (2,  9), (2, 10),
(3, 11), (3, 12), (3, 13), (3, 14), (3, 15);
```

And we want is top 3 (in order of latest id) value per category concatenated:

```
select category, 
    group_concat(value order by id desc) as value_con
from (
    select t.*,
        @rn := if(@category = category, @rn + 1, if(@category := category,1, 1)) as seqnum
    from your_table t
    cross join (select @category := null, @rn := 0) x
    order by t.category, t.id desc
    ) t
where seqnum <= 3
group by category;
```

Output:

```
category    value_con
1           5,4,3
2           10,9,8
3           15,14,13
```

Here is a [demo](http://rextester.com/XWQZG28327) of this.

Comment: wow! so it is possible to put the where clause outside the subquery! this inadvertently solves my problem where i had nested subqueries and MySQL doesn't pass column references deeper than one level. so when i moved the where clause outside the subquery then column reference was on the first level and the query ran!


hmmm i guess if we google long enough we could find answers to anything! LOL

Answer (score 0):

For those cases where you cannot use a temp table, The best way I know of is to select an obscure separator and then truncate starting at the first instance of said character. This example uses the NUL character.

`select substring_index(group_concat(field separator '\0'), '\0', 5) from table;`

Where `field` is the name of the field, `5` is the number of results.

The drawback is if your first row contains that character, it will be a partial result.

A workaround would be to replace `'\0'` with a longer random string.

It's good to know that `field` could be replaced to include more information using `concat`.

Keep in mind the `group_concat_max_len` defaults to 1024 characters, so you should look into changing that either globally or within your application if you want more than that.