# "Unknown column" because of subquery-in-subquery

Tags: sql, mysql, subquery, mysql-error-1054

I need to do subquery in subquery what causes "Unknown column 't1.product_id' in 'where clause'". It's on line 7. in my example. How to solve this problem?

```
SELECT *,product_id id,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT (value ORDER By `order` ASC SEPARATOR ', ') 
    FROM (
        SELECT `order`,value 
        FROM slud_data 
        LEFT JOIN slud_types ON slud_types.type_id=slud_data.type_id 
        WHERE slud_data.product_id = t1.product_id 
          AND value!='' AND display=0 
        LIMIT 3
    ) tmp) text
FROM slud_products t1 
WHERE 
    now() < DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL +ttl DAY) AND activated=1
    ORDER BY t1.date DESC
```

This question continues from [LIMIT ignored in query with GROUP_CONCAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378324/limit-ignored-in-query-with-group-concat)

Comment: In the absence of an ORDER BY clause, LIMIT relies on the underlying structure of table indices, which (for some humans) is a bit unpredictable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a derived table/inline view, and table aliases:

```
  SELECT product_id AS id,
         GROUP_CONCAT (y.value ORDER BY y.`order`) 
    FROM slud_products t1 
    JOIN (SELECT sd.product_id, 
                 sd.value,
                 sd.`order`
            FROM SLUD_DATA sd 
       LEFT JOIN slud_types ON slud_types.type_id = slud_data.type_id 
           WHERE value! = '' 
             AND display = 0) y ON y.product_id = t1.product_id 
                               AND y.order <= 3
   WHERE now() < DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL +ttl DAY) 
     AND activated = 1
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY t1.date DESC
```

Comment: Hello, still wondering how "LIMIT 3" clause from original query is handled here ? What if `order` is not sequental field or not zero-based ?

Comment: @Dfr: `AND y.order <= 3` is a groupwise limit.  If the OP marked this as the answer, then it is safe to assume `order` is numeric...

Answer (score 3):

I have found it more comfortable to use variables in Queries with More than 2 Selects Deep.

```
SELECT *,@product := product_id id,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT (value ORDER By `order` ASC SEPARATOR ', ') 
    FROM (
        SELECT `order`,value 
        FROM slud_data 
        LEFT JOIN slud_types ON slud_types.type_id=slud_data.type_id 
        WHERE slud_data.product_id = @product
          AND value!='' AND display=0 
        LIMIT 3
    ) tmp) text
FROM slud_products t1 
WHERE 
    now() < DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL +ttl DAY) AND activated=1
    ORDER BY t1.date DESC
```

Comment: **DO NOT DO THIS!!!** It will not work reliably:  You're not guaranteed left-to-right evaluation order of SELECT expressions, so it's possible your subquery will be evaluated *before* `@product` is updated, for a given row.  From the manual:  "The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined. For example, there is no guarantee that SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1 evaluates @a first and then performs the assignment. ".  (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html).