# Fetching using group_concat in PHP/MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I was trying to get the list of usernames separated by comma(,) and I used this SQL:

```
$sql="select group_concat(concat(' ',username,' ')) as username from user";
$var=mysql_query($sql);
while($v=mysql_fetch_assoc($var)){ $variable=$v['username']; }
echo $variable;
```

**Ignore the mysql_* function here.**

The above SQL helped me to get the list of all user in the database and echo it but I got a problem when I used `LIMIT 3` and/or `ORDER BY rank` at the end like:

```
$sql="select group_concat(concat(' ',username,' ')) as username from user ORDER BY rank LIMIT 3";
```

After I add *ORDER BY....* there comes no change to the result.

Is there any way to fix the above code using `ORDER BY rank LIMIT 3` at end of SQL? or is there any other method to do it?

*Thanks in Advance!*

Comment: Please see this link. I think it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378324/limit-ignored-in-query-with-group-concat

Answer (score 2):

**fix**

> filter your users in subquery before passing to group_concat..

**adjusted query**

```
select group_concat(concat(' ',username,' ') ORDER BY rank ) as username 
from
(
select id, username, rank
from user
order by rank
limit 3
) filtered_users
;
```

**output**

```
+-----------------------+
|       username        |
+-----------------------+
| jonny , zelda , maria |
+-----------------------+
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/860e8/7)

Comment: Error: Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: did you copy+paste exactly - please check the fiddle

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(username )  
FROM user
GROUP BY id;

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php
```

please check this, This will help you.

Comment: please let me know if any more concern