# GROUP_CONCAT multiple values from table

Tags: mysql

I just added a table which holds a url and description for each item in place. The below query works ok ... but it's only returning the url and I need the desc also. I m not sure how to make this work.

```
$query_str = "SELECT      a.userid, a.cat, a.id, a.name, a.image, 
                          a.desc, a.country, b.user_id, c.username, 
                          c.fbook, d.cat_id,
                          (
                               SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(url) 
                               FROM one_add o 
                               WHERE a.id=o.one_id

                          ) AS url,
                          (
                               SELECT COUNT(id) 
                               FROM one_msg m 
                               WHERE m.guest_id = ? AND 
                                     m.one_id=a.id 
                          ) AS count
               FROM place a
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN wait b 
                                 ON a.id=b.post_id AND 
                                    b.user_id= ?
                            JOIN users c
                                 ON a.userid=c.id
                            LEFT JOIN ( 
                                       SELECT userid, user_id, 
                                              GROUP_CONCAT( cat_id ) AS cat_id 
                                       FROM user_cat 
                                       WHERE userid='$user_id' 
                                       GROUP BY user_id 
                                      ) AS d ON d.userid='$user_id' AND 
                                                d.user_id=a.userid
              WHERE a.cat != ? ORDER BY a.date desc";
```

This is what I want to accomplish:  `<a href="url">desc</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achibe this by using `CONCAT` inside `GROUP_CONCAT` function as:

```
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('<a href=\"',url,'\">',desc,'</a>')) 
 FROM one_add o 
 WHERE a.id=o.one_id) AS url
```

full query:

```
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM one_msg m WHERE m.guest_id = ? AND m.one_id=a.id ) AS count
FROM place a
LEFT OUTER JOIN wait b ON a.id=b.post_id AND b.user_id= ?
JOIN users c ON a.userid=c.id
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT userid, user_id, GROUP_CONCAT( cat_id ) AS cat_id FROM user_cat WHERE userid='$user_id' GROUP BY user_id ) AS d ON d.userid='$user_id' AND d.user_id=a.userid
WHERE a.cat != ? ORDER BY a.date desc";
```

Comment: Hi. Not sure why but it's giving me this: HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Comment: Ok ... not sure if this is correct but I made it work like this: `(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('<a href=$url>$desc</a>'))` And set up these two variables `$url ="url"; $desc = "desc";`

Comment: My mistake ... it s not working. That just returns the actual words url and desc.

Comment: that's because you need to escape quotes " like \" while assigning string top variable in PHP, see I have modified first query.

Comment: Is there any way to limit these ? Like LIMIT 5 or something

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522509/how-to-hack-mysql-group-concat-to-fetch-a-limited-number-of-rows