# SQL: Concat a column with a limit?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

What's a good way to concat a column based on a match with another column in MySQL? And possible add a limit?

Say my table looks like this:

```
City | State | Stores
----------------------
Miami  FL      Walmart
Miami  FL      Sams
Miami  FL      Target
Tampa  FL      Sears
Tampa  FL      Walgreens
```

And I want to get something like this:

```
City | State | Stores
----------------------
Miami  FL      Walmart, Sams, Target
Tampa  FL      Sears, Walgreens
```

Also, is it possible to set a limit on how many are concated? Say I want a limit of 2, in the above sample it would exclude Target after getting 2 items. Is this possible?

Comment: If limiting to two records per group, how do you decide *which* two to select?

Comment: @eggyal - thanks! I didn't know that, and didn't really know you could link to an answer until you pointed this out. I'll update the comment.

Comment: The GROUP_CONCAT from @FreshPrinceOfSO will string them together for you. To limit the number of stores, see [this StackOverflow answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10986929/2091410).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use both `GROUP_CONCAT` and `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to concatenate and then limit the number of values to return:

```
select city,
  state,
  substring_index(group_concat(stores SEPARATOR ', '), ', ', 2) stores
from yt                                                   -- ^ number of values to limit
group by city, state;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01267/6)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

```
SELECT City, State, GROUP_CONCAT(Stores SEPARATOR ', ') Stores
FROM table
GROUP BY City, State
```

**Result**

```
|  CITY | STATE |                STORES |
-----------------------------------------
| Miami |    FL | Walmart, Sams, Target |
| Tampa |    FL |     Sears, Walgreens  |
```

[See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d5f6/3)

Comment: The syntax that would be most suitable is `group_concat(stores separator ', ')`.