# MySQL Join two Tables to get records with limit from child

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, sql-order-by

I have two tables

`Technology

+--------+--------+

| tid(P) |  name  |

+--------+--------+

|   1    |   Java |

|--------|--------|

|   2    |   PHP  |

+--------+--------+`

**Employee**
+----------+----------+------------+
|  eid(P)  |  tid(F) ^| join_date  |
+----------+----------+------------+
|    1     |     1    | 2013-10-01 |
|----------|----------|------------|
|    2     |     1    | 2013-10-10 |
|----------|----------|------------|
|    3     |     1    | 2013-10-12 |
|----------|----------|------------|
|    4     |     1    | 2013-09-10 |
|----------|----------|------------|
|    5     |     1    | 2013-11-10 |
|----------|----------|------------|
|    6     |     1    | 2013-12-10 |
|----------|----------|------------|
|    7     |     2    | 2013-08-01 |
|----------|----------|------------|
|    8     |     2    | 2013-10-28 |
|----------|----------|------------|
|    9     |     2    | 2013-05-12 |
|----------|----------|------------|
|    10    |     2    | 2013-10-10 |
|----------|----------|------------|
|    11    |     2    | 2013-11-10 |
|----------|----------|------------|
|    12    |     2    | 2013-12-05 |
|----------|----------|------------|

I need to get data of **recently joined three employees for each technology**.
I tried different joins and also did google on this but didn't get any success.

`Expected Result

+-------+--------+-------+------------+

|  tid  |  name  |  eid  | join_date  |

+-------+--------+-------+------------+

|   1   |  Java  |   6   | 2013-12-10 |

+-------+--------+-------+------------+

|   1   |  Java  |   5   | 2013-11-10 |

+-------+--------+-------+------------+

|   1   |  Java  |   3   | 2013-10-12 |

+-------+--------+-------+------------+

|   2   |  PHP   |   12  | 2013-12-05 |

+-------+--------+-------+------------+

|   2   |  PHP   |   11  | 2013-11-10 |

+-------+--------+-------+------------+

|   2   |  PHP   |   8   | 2013-10-28 |

+-------+--------+-------+------------+`

What should be my query?

Please guide.

Thanks,
Ankur

Comment: +1 for taking the effort to nicely format your tables, though the fact that the first table doesn't *quite* line up is giving me a few twitches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.tid, A.name, A.eid, A.join_date 
FROM (SELECT IF(@tid = @tid:=t.tid, @cnt:=@cnt+1, @cnt:=0) rowNo, t.tid, t.name, e.eid, e.join_date 
      FROM Technology t 
      INNER JOIN Employee e ON t.tid = e.tid, (SELECT @tid:=0, @cnt:=0) A
      ORDER BY t.tid, e.join_date DESC
     ) AS A
WHERE A.rowNo < 3;
```

**EDIT::**

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT *, IF(@tid=@tid:=result.tid,@count:=@count+1,@count:=0) as pos
    FROM
        (SELECT t.tid, t.name, e.eid, e.join_date
          FROM Technology t
          JOIN Employee e
          WHERE e.tid = t.tid
          ORDER BY t.tid, e.join_date DESC) result
          JOIN (SELECT @tid:=0, @count:=0) c) finalre
where finalre.pos < 3;
```

Comment: I think it should be LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of INNER(In question "recently joined three employees for each technology")

Comment: check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html
AND Sqlfiddle 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/794858/1

Comment: @Saharsh: With you query i am getting 6 rows only but not getting in correct order. I am trying to get that. Please if you can look into that.

Comment: @AnkurRaiyani If you find that you got your answer than `Accept` the answer which is useful to you

Comment: @SaharshShah I have `Accept` it, Just a suggestion, i think you should edit this answer with below correct answer. So other can get the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

```
SELECT T.tid,T.name, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(eid ORDER BY join_date DESC), ',', 3) AS `eid`,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(join_date ORDER BY join_date DESC), ',', 3) AS `join_date`
FROM Technology T LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee E
ON E.tid = T.tid
GROUP BY T.tid
```

Here if you need x entries just change the count variable in SUBSTRING_INDEX to x
You need to process the field eid and join_date in your application logic. You can try some string tokenizer.
Here is the [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/794858/7)

REF: [How to hack MySQL GROUP_CONCAT to fetch a limited number of rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522509/how-to-hack-mysql-group-concat-to-fetch-a-limited-number-of-rows/10986929#10986929)

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the result !!!

Thanks a lot to **[Saharsh Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1784834/saharsh-shah)**. From his answer, i am able to solve this problem.

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT *, IF(@tid=@tid:=result.tid,@count:=@count+1,@count:=0) as pos
    FROM
        (SELECT t.tid, t.name, e.eid, e.join_date
          FROM Technology t
          JOIN Employee e
          WHERE e.tid = t.tid
          ORDER BY t.tid, e.join_date DESC) result
          JOIN (SELECT @tid:=0, @count:=0) c) finalre
where finalre.pos < 3;
```

Please check at [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/794858/11/0)