# mysql query and php code for display ul li data

Tags: php, mysql

i have two table `tbl_category`

```
id category 
1   cat1 
2   cat2
3   cat3
```

and second table `Tbl_book`

```
id  cat_id  book_name
1    1      book1
2    1      book2
3    2      book4
4    1      book5
```

mysql query and php code for display

```
 cat1  book1  book2 book5 
 cat2  book4
```

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
select c.category, 
       group_concat(b.bookname separator ' ') as books
from tbl_category c
inner join tbl_book b on b.cat_id = c.id
group by c.category
```

Comment: thank for help one more ques i want 5 book limit then

Comment: One way to do it would be described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23608554/575376