# MySQL Union All - value priority

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query that `UNION` two tables and retrieves the `SUM` of some fields and other information as you can see:

```
SELECT SUM(a.quantity_input) AS `quantity_input`, 
       SUM(a.quantity_output) AS `quantity_output`,  
       a.average_cost_price, 
       a.item_reference, 
       a.item_description
FROM   ((SELECT SUM(aco.quantity_input)     AS `quantity_input`, 
                SUM(aco.quantity_output)    AS `quantity_output`, 
                aco.average_cost_price, 
                item.reference              AS `item_reference`, 
                item.description            AS `item_description`
         FROM   stock_accumulated AS aco 
         INNER JOIN items AS item ON item.id = aco.item_id
         WHERE aco.year = '2016' AND 
               aco.month < '03'
         GROUP  BY item.reference) 

        UNION ALL 

        (SELECT Sum(mov.quantity_input)    AS `input_quantity`, 
                Sum(mov.quantity_output)   AS `quantity_output`, 
                mov.average_cost_price, 
                item.reference             AS `item_reference`, 
                item.description           AS `item_description`
         FROM   stock_movements AS mov 
         INNER JOIN items AS item ON item.id = mov.item_id 
         WHERE mov.movement_date <= '2016-03-31' AND 
               mov.movement_date >= '2016-03-01'
         GROUP  BY item.reference)) a 
GROUP  BY a.item_reference
```

My only problem (at least so far) with this query is that I need to retrieve the `average_cost_price` of the last row in my second  table.

You can try the following query in **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54ef0/1)** and see the image below to understand what I'm referring to.

[image]

Comment: If you want to retrieve the "last" average cost price, you'll need a (potentially complicated) subquery to retrieve it... and to define what you mean by "last"

Comment: Eching Uueerdo's question:  *which* row from \`mov\` is the "last" row for a given value of \`item_reference\` ... the one with the largest value of \`movement_date\`? What if there are multiple rows with the same latest \`movement_date\`? And different values of \`item\`.\`id\`? Which of those rows is the "last" one?

Comment: @spencer7593, my SQLFiddle is wrong in the ID's..obviously it's auto-incremented so its (1, 2, 3) and not (1, 1, 1). I want to retrieve the last ID, in this case it would be the line 3 with value 37.30. Please see the new SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54ef0/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

I had to use `group_concat` function that provides the ability to order a field.

```
group_concat(mov.average_cost_price ORDER BY mov.id DESC SEPARATOR ",")
```

But this function returns all the values, and since I can't use the `LIMIT` function I used the `substring_index` function to return me only one value.

```
substring_index(group_concat(mov.average_cost_price ORDER BY mov.id DESC SEPARATOR ","), ",", 1) as `average_cost_price`
```

[GROUP_CONCAT with limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608464/group-concat-with-limit)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "tightening" up your Where statement with the date? It could be pulling the first occurence. I would recommend testing

```
WHERE mov.movement_date <= '2016-03-31' AND 
               mov.movement_date >= '2016-03-01'

as

WHERE mov.movement_date <= '2016-03-31' AND 
               mov.movement_date >= '2016-03-27'
```

Then you can mark that off if it doesnt work.
Lemme know ill try to help you.

Comment: I cant change the `movement_date`. I had a few problems in my previous SQLFiddle, please see the new one. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54ef0/1