# SQL query to mysql (Subquery does not recognize outer table)

Tags: mysql, sql-query-store

I know mysql does not recognize the outer table from a subquery, but sadly I have no idea how to solve this.

**First the table structure, I have three tables (m to n):**

Table1:
 **dance**

```
 TID | Name_Of_The_Dance   
 12  | Heute Tanz ich
```

Table2:
 **dancer**

```
TAID | Name_Of_Dancer
 1 | Alex Womitsch  
 2 | Julian Berger
```

Table3 (Referencing table):
 **dance2dancer**

```
TID | TAID   
 12 | 213   
 12 | 345
```

**What do I want to achieve (output):**

```
TID | AllDancerWhoDance  
12 |  213---,345---,0---,0---,0---,0---,0---,0---,0---,0---
```

Every output should have the dance TID and all dancer who dance in this dance. But AllDancerWhoDance should be filled up with "0---", when we have less than 10 dancer. When we have more than 10 dancer in this dance, the query should decrease the string to a maximum of 10 dancer.

More examples to unterstand:
A dance with 4 dancers should be filled up with 6 zeros:

```
9 | 213---,345---,111---,459---,0---,0---,0---,0---,0---,0---
```

Do we have a dance with more than 10 dancers the query should decrease it to 10:

```
9 | 213---,345---,111---,459---,333---,444---,445---,222---,192---,490--- (NO more zeros or dancer TAIDs)
```

**And here is my query:**

```
select dancer.tid, 
    IF(count(dancer.taid) <= 10, 
        CONCAT_WS("",GROUP_CONCAT(dancer.taid,"&&&"), REPEAT(";0",10-count(dancer.taid)))
      , (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a.taid,"&&&") from (SELECT ttt.taid from dance2dancer ttt inner join dance taenz on ttt.tid = taenz.tid where ttt.tid = dance.tid LIMIT 10) as a)
      ) AS "AllDancerWhoDance"
from dance inner join dance2dancer tt on dance.tid = tt.tid inner join dancer on tt.taid = dancer.taid group by dance.tid
```

I think it would work but the problem is that the subquery does not look into the outer table and the "where" clause is not working:
**where ttt.tid = dance.tid**

**And now my questions:**
How can I achieve this sql query working in mysql?

Thank you

**//UPDATE**
Because many people asking for the front end code and why I would need this query: We have an 22 years old software, that needs this data in such a format. It was programed from a company which does not exists anymore and we do not have any source code of this program. We have changed the database and website to this new datamodel (m:n) but the old program still needs the data in the old format. Therefore I need this strange query.
And yes, we are working on a new program as well.

Comment: I can't think of a sensible reason for constructing such an odd string. :-$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your error is that you cannot access outer columns from inside a derived table (your `from (...) as a`). To do it, you have to write something like `(...) as a where a.tid = dancer.tid`, so you put the `where` outside of the derived table; but you obviously have to rewrite `a` in a way to have `tid` as a column.

In your case, it would be more complicated to fix your code, so I wrote you an (easier) new one:

```
select tid,
  CONCAT_WS("",
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(d2d2.taid,"---") 
   from dance2dancer d2d2
   where d2d2.tid = d2d.tid 
   group by d2d2.tid limit 10),
  REPEAT(",0---",10-count(distinct d2d.taid))
  ) as `AllDancerWhoDance`
from dance2dancer d2d
group by d2d.tid
```

And a warning: this kind of query (using group_concat or concat in a column) is only to be used in a final step to format the data you want to display. If you plan to use it in another query, e.g. something like `select * from dancer where INSTR('213---,345---,111---', taid) > 0`, please don't, just rewrite it.

**Update** without using `limit 10`:

Although `limit 10` should work with group_concat (it works for me), in case it doesn't work for you, you can of course just concat everything and then take the first 10 entries of the concated string afterwards. It would actually simplify the query, since you don't need the subquery anymore (that only was there to have the `limit` in the first place), but might generate a large temporary string (before `substring_index`) if you have a dance with A LOT of dancers.

```
select tid,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT_WS("",
  GROUP_CONCAT(d2d.taid,"---"),
  REPEAT(",0---",10-count(distinct d2d.taid)),
  ','
  ), ',',10) as `AllDancerWhoDance`
from dance2dancer d2d
group by d2d.tid;
```

or calculate a rownumber beforehand and just take the first 10 rows per tid:

```
select d2d.tid, CONCAT_WS("",
  GROUP_CONCAT(d2d.taid,"---"),
  REPEAT(",0---",10-d2d.cnt)
  ) as `AllDancerWhoDance`
from 
(select tid, taid, 
      (select count(*) 
       from dance2dancer d2d4
       where d2d4.tid = d2d3.tid
       and d2d4.taid <= d2d3.taid
      ) as rownum,
      (select count(*) 
       from dance2dancer d2d4
       where d2d4.tid = d2d3.tid
      ) as cnt
      from dance2dancer d2d3
) as d2d
where d2d.rownum <= 10
group by d2d.tid;
```

Comment: Thank you for your replies. 

@Solarflare: The query is great, there is only a problem with GROUP_CONCAT and Limit. It does not work together.

for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608464/group-concat-with-limit

And when I rewrite your query to:
select tid,
  CONCAT_WS("",
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a.taid,"---") 
   (select d2d.taid from dance2dancer d2d2
   where d2d2.tid = d2d.tid limit 10)) as a,
  REPEAT(";0---",10-count(distinct d2d.taid))
  ) as `AllDancerWhoDance`
from dance2dancer d2d
group by d2d.tid

And again problem with the outer columns :-/

Comment: What's your mysql-version? `Limit` works for me, but nevertheless I added 2 versions without `limit`. Make sure to really copy&paste it 1:1 to exclude mistakes that may occur from rewriting it (your rewritten code you pasted here lacks at least a `from`).

Comment: Thank you very much. The query is working fine :-)

But I wonder why "Limit" is working on your machine? 
Because also Oracle hasn`t fixed this: 
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=30098
I have tested this code with MySQL version 5.5.46 and 5.5.28

Answer (score 0):

To get 10 dancer for a given dance do this :

```
select D.Name_Of_Dancer 
from  dancer DR, dance2dancer DD
where DD.taid = DR.taid 
groupby DD.tid
Limit 10
```

You can also add Desc or ASC to sort the list of dancer list and extract first 10 dancer.

But to get minimum 10 dancer in a list even if it doesn't exist. Its not possible by mysql.  What I mean is show me the code on front end how are you handling, what we can do is count the number of results. if results are 4 we can simply use a loop to create 6 other entries to get total 10 dancer. But I dont recommend handling them from mysql end. Its a bad practice.

Comment: Not possible in a sense its a bad practice. The idea of database is to store records, fetch records etc but not to create empty records nit really a good idea. Why not handle in the page or view

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.

Comment: Yea, so if you could show your front end code. I could be of some help. Also why its good on frontend side is that its just for the page sake that we want to show 10 results and if not many existing then simply adding zero or null on front end. As it would keep your querying simple and clean. And dynamically generate extra bits on front end.